# Unity - Saving Level Changes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a small RPG and a problem came up when I enter my house where there is a chest and I opened the chest to get an item, I then leave the house which changes the scene and come back into the house with the chest still able to be opened.

What I am looking for is when certain items (such as chests) are opened they stay opened throughout the game even on scene changes.  There is probably more than one way to handle this but the only thing that came to mind was maybe using PlayerPrefs but I wanted to get some feedback if anyone had an easier way of approaching something like this.

Comment: I would use my own serialized classes for this.  But if you're doing it on the web, it's probably better to stick with PlayerPrefs if you aren't stuffing a huge amount of data in.  E.G. if your save data is going to be very small, playerprefs is fine, otherwise you should look into serializing your own data.

Comment: Ok Let me look at what you said and do some research on this. @ThisHandleNotInUse

Comment: There are many many ways to store data in C#.  I prefer constructing my own classes to handle this kind of stuff, but another option would be SQL: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/188334/unity-sql-database.html

Here's a tutorial on basic serialization: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yqKylTd8dtM

Comment: @ThisHandleNotInUse OK, so I just watched both of the videos and let me know if I am going in the right direction as this is very new to me.  I will basically do no serialization of my chest the first time it is loaded (Chest has not been opened yet) since it isn't in the file to be de-serialized?  Then when the chest is opened it is then written to the file that it has been and I will serialize information so that when I de-serialize it will read that it has been opened and with that information I can spawn an opened chest?

Comment: You should create your own class object that can store all the preferences you will need for your game.  When someone saves, you serialize all this data at once - otherwise it sits in memory waiting to be saved.  For example, I have a class that works like PlayerPrefs in that I can insert and get bools, strings, floats, etc by keyword, but it doesn't have a size limit and it saves to a file the harddisk.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, you want to save state of the scene with chest object. You shouldn't allow unity engine to destroy your chest object when entering next scene.

Use this method

```
DontDestroyOnLoad (transform.gameObject);
```

[Read more on the Unity3D website.](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/56245/what-is-the-best-way-to-save-a-scene-state-in-game.html)

Comment: That's quite dumb because when you reboot the game, the changes will be gone again